# 3d objects in actionscript 3 without plugins

Tags: actionscript-3

I am fairly new to actionscript and was wondering is it possible to create 3d shapes (cones, spheres, cubes) using actionscript.

I would like not to have to use a plugin.

The shapes must be 3d as I need to rotate them.

Comment: I did 3 blog posts on 3D shapes without external libraries: http://blog.leeburrows.com/2010/10/drawtriangles1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find Adobes documentation for what you are looking for:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS7D38179D-58B9-409c-9E5C-257DDECB1A02.html

Is there any specific reason that you don't want to use 3D libraries like away3D?

Comment: Thanks for this. It is a project that I am very restricted on.

Answer (score 0):

I think Matej's answer does not fully cover the topic as the link he gave only describes a classic display list approach to drawing 3D objects. Depending on your needs, drawing things using classic display list can be slow, as it is not GPU accelerated. If you want to utilize your GPU you can use Stage3D APIs - that does not require any external frameworks. [Here's](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/how-stage3d-works.html) an excellent article for starters.
And even though you can render 3D content using 'raw' Context3D, I`d recommend using a framework like Away3D or Alternativa3D. Both are open source, by the way.